# Simple Jasmine Async Test causes timeout

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I am struggling to get a simple test to run on an async function in a module. I am trying to get my head around testing and so have built a working module and manually tested it in repl.it

http://repl.it/7Qf

My module looks like this:

```
var weather = (function() {
    var location;
    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=';

    function getData(loc, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url+loc, true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } else {
                    callback(JSON.parse(xhr.statusText));
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.error(xhr.statusText);
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    return {
        getTemp: function(location, callback) {
            getData(location, function(data) {
                var temp = data.main.temp.toFixed(2);
                callback(temp);
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

My test suite looks like this:

```
describe("Weather Module", function() {
    it('get temperature', function(done) {
        weather.getTemp('coventry,uk', function(data){
            console.log(data);
            expect(data).toBe(2.66);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I get a timeout error when I run this test. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

EDIT: I tried a different approach but get the same error.

```
describe("Weather Module", function() {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        this.temp = null;
        weather.getTemp('coventry, uk', function(data) {
            this.temp = data;
            done();
        });
    });
    it('should get temp', function() {
        expect(this.temp).toBe(2.66);
    });

});
```

I still get this error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: Are you opposed to mocking out the AJAX call? Maybe you're getting a timeout because of the request to the API. What exactly is throwing the timeout error?

Comment: I don't know enough about the topic to be able to answer either of your questions. Could you show me how to mock the call? The error is a timeout but I don't know what is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. This happens because of default interval of Jasmine which is set to 5000 ms.

I added following line to the beginning of my test script file:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;// set your time here
```

which means that Jasmine will wait for done() function 20 sec before failing the test.